# Material ProgressDialog wrong style

Tags: android

Seems like there are either two `ProgressDialogs` or there is a second background ?
The picture says it all :

[image]

And the code i'm using :

```
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(),
            R.style.ProgressDialog);

    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Updating Profile...");
    progressDialog.show();
```

where the style is :

```
    <style name="ProgressDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/app_body_text_disabled</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here discussed exactly about your problem. Hope it will help

[Dialog skinning with AppCompat-v7 22 results in ugly shadows on api < 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608126/dialog-skinning-with-appcompat-v7-22-results-in-ugly-shadows-on-api-21)