# Copy/paste menu with strange rectangle on AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am creating a AlertDialog with this custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code that I use to create and show the dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_layout, null);
builder.setView(dialogView);
builder.create().show();
```

When I try to copy some text from my EditText the copy/paste menu appears with a weird rectangle that hide the EditText.

[image]

I have test it on Marshmallow and Nougat, both with the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608126/dialog-skinning-with-appcompat-v7-22-results-in-ugly-shadows-on-api-21), the problem is related to styles. In this case, removing the bacgkround color item from my custom AlertDialog style fixed the problem.